# Dynamically added select change events not registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange, html-select

In my site I have some code as follows: -

```
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
            var formID = $(this).attr("id");
                if((formID.indexOf("forms[")>-1)){

                var newFormID= $(this).val();
                var scenarioID = ${testScenarioInstance?.id}
                getFormInformation(newFormID, "forms", $(this), scenarioID);
            }
        });
    });
```

In another part of the page the user can add additional selects via a simple little post and append.  The trouble is for any newly added selects this piece of code doesn't trigger, but it works fine for any select that is there when the page loads.  Any ideas why this is?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: It should work. Can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: As a side note: you don't need to wrap it inside document ready handler. But anyway, your code should work

Comment: make sure you include the jquery file before you include the file where this code is held in, otherwise it won't work.
just giving you a pointer, since this code is already correct

Comment: the var `scenarioID` is wierd..

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - whats weird about that var?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work well as you have it now, here I made little example with your same code for the event:

http://jsfiddle.net/2KCY9/

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    alert("Works well");
});
```

Comment: My apologies all I was being an idiot, the page that loads when I'm creating a new has different html to when I'm editing, and I hadn't even put this code into the create page!  Unsurprisingly it works fine when the code is actually there!